# Is it safe to restart system calls?

Tags: linux-kernel, signals, system-calls, interrupt

I was reading a textbook which describes how to deal with system call when interrupted:

> System calls can be interrupted. System calls such as read, wait, and accept that can potentially block the process for a long period of time are called slow system calls. On some older versions of Unix, slow system calls that are interrupted when a handler catches a signal do not resume when the signal handler returns but instead return immediately to the user with an error
> condition and errno set to EINTR. On these systems, programmers must include code that manually restarts interrupted system calls.

But is it always safe to restart system calls?
Let's say a system call maintains an internal data structure that needs to be reset before the system call finishes. So we start the system call and it is long running and blocked, when a signal interrupts it, the system call just restarts, so the first system call doesn't have a chance to reset the data structure.

Since the data structure in the previous call wasn't get reset, after the second system call occurs, the data structure is not consistent, which might pollute the operation.

So is it safe to restart system calls?

Comment: Could you please site which textbook it refers to? We probably want to read the context to get more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, yes, it is always safe to restart a system call which returned with `EINTR`: that return value means that the system call was interrupted before it made any useful progress, and should be restarted. The system call’s implementation takes this into account.

Cases where the system state has changed because of the interrupted system call are handled differently; for example, a [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) call which retrieved some data before it was interrupted will return that data, indicating success, and a [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) call which transferred some data before it was interrupted will return the amount of data it wrote, also indicating success. (Incidentally, this is one of the reasons it’s essential to check the return values of these functions and not assume that successful calls did all the work requested.)

Many system calls can be automatically restarted, by setting the `SA_RESTART` flag for the appropriate signals. The GNU C library provides a macro which can help write restarting code, [`TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY` in `unistd.h`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Interrupted-Primitives.html) (defined if `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined).

Note that on Linux, system calls can return `EINTR` even without a signal handler.

The “Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers” section of [`man 7 signal`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) has all the details, including lists of affected system calls in the various scenarios.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So can I say all system calls are async signal safe functions?

Comment: I think so, yes, although they can be used in unsafe ways (*e.g.* `read` into the same buffer in a signal handler and code running outside the handler). System calls need to be reentrant anyway, or at least callable in parallel from multiple contexts.